# Adding objects in an array to a searchable list

Tags: android, object, arraylist

I am trying to populate a searchlist with the "name" data from an object. Then I want to be able to click the object and send the object to the next activity. I got it working using strings only, but with the objects I get all kinds of errors. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? Here is the code so far.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity
{
    public final static String sampleObject = "no.uib.nutritionapplication.dene";
    private ListView list;
    private EditText edText;
    private ArrayList<FoodItem> array_sort= new ArrayList<FoodItem>();
    int textlength = 0;   

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    ArrayList<FoodItem> foodList = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();

    FoodItem orange_juice = new FoodItem("Orange juice", 10, 2, 100, 140, "Orange juice from concentrate");
    FoodItem bread = new FoodItem("Bread", 12, 5, 150, 160, "Whole grain bread");
    FoodItem jarlsberg = new FoodItem("Jarlsberg cheese", 8, 8, 130, 180, "Jarlsberg cheese");

    foodList.add(orange_juice);
    foodList.add(bread);
    foodList.add(jarlsberg);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    edText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<FoodItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foodList));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
                long rowId) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, AddMealActivity.class);

            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;  
            FoodItem message = textView.getName().toString();  

            intent.putExtra("sampleObject", message);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    edText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textlength = edText.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= foodList.getName()[i].length()) {
                    if(edText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)foodList.getName()[i].subSequence(0,textlength))){
                        array_sort.add(foodList.getName()[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
            }
        }
    );


    }

}
```

Comment: [See this Example...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own adapter for this.

Check out the following tutorial for more information:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<FoodItem> values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FoodItem> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(values.get(position).NAMEOFFOOD);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```